# Spring batch is storing epoch time in database

Tags: spring-batch

When i ran my spring batch job it is storing its job parameters details in **BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS** table in DB, but i saw a weird thing at **DATE_VAL** column in the **BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS** table. Spring batch is inserting epoch time for all job parameters.

I looked at the class file in java decompiler and i found

```
if (type == JobParameter.ParameterType.STRING) {
  args = new Object[] { executionId, key, type, value, new Timestamp(0L), Long.valueOf(0L), Double.valueOf(0.0D), identifyingFlag };
}
```

in the above code they are creating a object for job parameter with "**new Timestamp(0L)**" i.e, epoch time.

```
INSERT into %PREFIX%JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS(JOB_EXECUTION_ID, KEY_NAME, TYPE_CD, STRING_VAL, DATE_VAL, LONG_VAL, DOUBLE_VAL, IDENTIFYING) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"), args, argTypes)
```

The above insert statement accepts this args Object and inserting job parameters into DB. I think this is causing the issue of inserting epoch time in to DB.

Answer (score 0):

That line of code you're showing only occurs when the type of the parameter is a String.  If it's an actual date, it would be set appropriately.

Comment: Yes my job parameter type is String. So is it a bug in framework itself. why they do not make it null.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug.  The behavior is the same with every other value type.